# React-redux mapStateToProps not received in the componentDidMount

Tags: reactjs, redux

So I've rewrote my code a bit to use state instead of modifying props since it is not what I should do. The problem that occurred now is that when componentDidMount runs props are still not fetched from the backend, therefore the if statements in the function are always false.

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getTypes('sport');
    this.props.getSchema();
    this.props.getDomainForm();

    if(Object.keys(this.props.schema).length) {
        this.setState({schema: this.props.schema})
    }
    if(Object.keys(this.props.formData).length) {
        this.setState({form: this.props.formData})
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        schema: state.admin.settings.Domains.schema.data || {},
        formData: state.admin.settings.Domains.domain.data || {},
        types: state.admin.settings.Domains.types.data || {},
    }
};
```

I've stepped trough the code and it seems like componentDidMount runs only once. Since `componentWillRecieveProps` is deprecated I am unsure what to do to fix this, and I hope you guys can help me with this one.

PS. there is no problems with fetch actions and reducers works perfectly I haven't changed anything there and redux debugger is displaying the results correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a replacement of `componentWillReceiveProps` there was introduced `static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state)` method, it's called each time component receives new props, so it might be helpful for you. Here's the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops).

Comment: That could work, but static methods have this = undefined, so i can't set the state

Comment: @Giedrius, you have to return an update object (the same you pass to `setState()`) from that method (it will be automatically applied to state) or `null`, if state update is not needed.

Answer (score 4):

i think the problem is your fetch is async and it takes little bit time to accomplish the task, and before the fetch is been finished , your component mounts on the DOM. 
as you noted you can see the data is been received via redux debugger and you have no problem with it , so i'm guessing that you passed the initial state as empty object or array to your state. so then your component receives data through props and you are not updating the state to reRender the component , what you need to do is just use `componentWillReceiveProps` to update the state whenever the new data is been received by just checking if current props is not equal to previous props , some code like this :

```
componentWillReceiveProps = (nextProps) => {
    if(this.props.yourPropsFromRedux != nextProps.yourPropsFromRedux ) {
      this.setState({ yourState: nextProps.yourPropsFromRedux })
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, as I noted in the description `componentWillRecieveProps` is deprecated so I am looking for another way to solve it

Comment: The [official React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html) explains how you can migrate your unsafe method  `componentWillReceiveProps` with `componentDidUpdate` & `getDerivatedStateFromProps`.

Answer (score -1):

Using `componentDidUpdate` along with `componentDidMount` is more suitable for this situation. `componentDidMount` will set the state for initial render and `componentDidUpdate` will set state for future renders. Don't forget to test the prevProps parameter of the `componentDidUpdate` method with current props to check if the data has changed or not. Read the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) here